# Cache table with Entity Framework Core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I have a database (SQL Server for your information but I don't think it's very important) with some tables, and a ASP.NET Core web application who implements Entity Framework Core to manage data.

In my database, I have 4 tables who are very often used and joined to almost each requests, and the data in this tables are very rarely updated, si I would like to put them in cache to not fetch data in database each time, but only for this tables.

How can I do that with Entity Framework Core ?

I read the documentation but I didn't found anything about caching : https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest

Comment: Ok... this issue on GitHub let me think there is nothing available yet in Entity Framework Core for caching : https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5858

Comment: I have to deal with ASP.NET Core caching module https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/performance/caching/index.html

Comment: Have tried https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/performance/caching/memory.html ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **StackExchange.Redis** cache for that.You just need to store your tables data on it and invalidate it when tables will be updated.That is it.

Here is the Link : [**StackExchange.Redis**](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to use "cached" table rows in your EF queries. You can cache tables (in redis, memory - any on your choice), but when you will make queries to your DB - you will need to perform additional manual processing in your code (in server memory) for joining results from EF with cached tables.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, EF doesn't have caching. NHibernate however has excellent caching support. It's a little bit painful to have to use EF now instead of NHibernate, but NHibernate doesn't support Core quite yet.